# How to add two dashes in a number?

Tags: angular, typescript

In output, I would like to display a number with this type of format => `979-9638403-03`.

Currently, the number is displayed like this => `979963840303`.

portfolio.ts

```
export class Portfolio {
    ...
    DEPO: number;         /* DEPO */
    
    constructor() {
        ...
        this.DEPO = 0;   /* DEPO */
    }
}
```

online.component.html

```
{{ ((currentPortfolio$ | async)?.DEPO) }}
```

Do you know if it is possible to add dashes? This is an aesthetic improvement.

I retrieve the value from a webservice for information.

I don't know if it's possible or not to do this on Angular?

Comment: is the length of DEPO field constantly?

Comment: Yes, on this point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Angular's [Slice Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe) :

If you convert the number to string you can do something like:

```
{{ '979963840303' | slice:0:3 }}-{{ '979963840303' | slice:3:-2 }}-{{ '979963840303' | slice:-2 }}
```

And that will output:

`979-9638403-03`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem is that `DEPO` is not a string. `Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | null | undefined'.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | null | undefined'.`

Comment: In that case, if you want to convert the value to string only on the template and not on the component, you could do something like:  {{ '' + DEPO | slice:0:3 }}. That way, the slice pipe will recieve the string resulting from concatenating  '' with DEPO.

Comment: You could also write your one PipeTransform, which would recieve your number, convert it to string, add the dashes... Depends on how much time you want to dedicate to it. NOTE: if you do, be vigilant about potential performance issues with your custom pipe when the template renders.